# How can i have an evaluation within a scope variable using ngRepeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I've create a custom directive that has a set of nested ngrepeats. The outer repeats data for rows. The inner repeats column templates.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in data">
    <div ng-repeat="col in columns">
        {{col.templateContent}}
    </div>
</div>
```

The collections are like this

```
$scope.data = [
    {firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe', email: 'email@test.com'},
    {firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe', email: 'email@test.com'},
    {firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe', email: 'email@test.com'},
];

$scope.columns = [
    {templateContent: '{{item['firstName']}} {{item['lastName']}}'}
];
```

When this runs it displays the templateContent as a string "{{item['firstName']}} {{item['lastName']}}". How can get the content of the variable to evaluate dynamcially?

They would be used like this.

```
<datagrid endpoint="User" query="userQuery" enable-paging="true" aggregate-search="search">
    <templatecolumn header-text="Name">
       {{firstName}} {{lastName}}
    </templatecolumn>
</datagrid>
```

Here are my two directives.

```
app.directive('templatecolumn', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: false,
        transclude:true,
        scope: {
            headerText: '@',
            enableSorting: '@'
        },
        require: '^datagrid',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, parentController, transclude) {

            transclude(scope, function (clone) {
                // clone is transcluded content
                scope.enableSorting = scope.enableSorting === 'false' ? false : scope.enableSorting !== false;

                parentController.addColumn({
                    isTemplateColumn: true,
                    headerText: scope.headerText,
                    enableSorting: scope.enableSorting,
                    templateContent: clone.html().replace(/{{/g, "{{item['").replace(/}}/g, "']}}")
                });
            });
        },
        template: '<div></div>'

    };
});



app.directive('datagrid', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            endpoint: '@',
            query: '=',
            enablePaging: '@',
            keyField: '@',
            aggregateSearch: '='
        },
        transclude:true,
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: 'app/ui/partials/datagrid.html',
        compile: function ($element, $attrs, linker) {
            if (!$attrs.keyField) { $attrs.keyField = 'id'; } // keyField = id as default
        },
        controller: ['$scope', 'dataSvc', function ($scope, dataSvc) {
            $scope.columns = [];
            $scope.data = [];


            $scope.recordsPerPage = 10;
            $scope.orderby = '';
            $scope.totalRecords = 0;
            $scope.currentPage = 1;
            $scope.aggregateFilterQuery = '';

            $scope.dataService = new dataSvc($scope.endpoint);

            $scope.loadGrid = function (orderby) {

                if (orderby) {
                    if ($scope.orderby.substring(0, orderby.length) === orderby) { // if same property as previous sort
                        if ($scope.orderby.indexOf(' desc') == -1) { // toggle desc/asc
                            orderby = orderby + ' desc';
                        } else {
                            orderby = orderby.replace(' desc', '');
                        }
                    }
                    $scope.orderby = orderby;
                }

                $scope.query
                    .orderby($scope.orderby)
                    .skip(($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.recordsPerPage)
                    .top($scope.recordsPerPage);

                if ($scope.aggregateSearch && $scope.aggregateFilterQuery) {
                    $scope.query.filter($scope.aggregateFilterQuery.replace(/{{search}}/g, $scope.aggregateSearch));
                }

                $scope.dataService.get($scope.query).success(function (data) {
                    $scope.data = data.value;
                    $scope.totalRecords = data['@odata.count'];
                });
            };

            $scope.$watch('aggregateSearch', function () { $scope.loadGrid(); });

            $scope.delete = function(id) {
                $scope.dataService.delete(id).success(function () {
                    $scope.loadGrid();
                });
            };

            this.addColumn = function (column) {
                $scope.columns.push(column);

                if (column.enableAggregateFilter) {
                    $scope.aggregateFilterQuery += ($scope.aggregateFilterQuery ? " or " : "") + "contains(" + column.dataitem + ", '{{search}}')";
                }
            }
        }]
    };
});
```

Comment: Update your snippets with directive pls

Comment: I'm confused on why you're using an array of columns with just a single entry in there.  I think you need to rethink the strategy.  With what you have at the moment, you can just put {{item.firstName}} {{item.lastName}} in place of the entire nested div and it would work.

Comment: what is the required result? if you just need 2 cols with firstname and lastname, it's just an ng-repate item in data with item.firstName / item.lastName as variables

Comment: I've simplified my code in this example to make my problem more clear. In reality the columns would vary and could be more complex but the approach would stay the same as this example.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in data">
    <div ng-repeat="col in columns">
        {{col(item)}}
    </div>
</div>
```

And update your columns to:

```
$scope.columns = [
    function(item) { return item.firstName + ' ' + item.lastName; }
];
```

Comment: This won't achieve what I'm wanting. What I would like is to be able to pull from the html the structure of the columns. I'd like to be able to take the contents of the <templateColumn> and have it rendered against the scope of the datagrid directive